# Difference between IC 74LS47 and 7446N

Tags: integrated-circuit, decoder

What are the major differences between these two **IC**s **74LS47** and **7446N** whose working is mostly the same ?
Both are used as *BCD* to *7 segment* decoder driver

Comment: Have you studied and compared the **datasheets**? Do realize that ICs exist that **perform the same function** from the same or different manufacturers (74LS logic is made / used to be made by many manufacturers). Some ICs perform the same function yet are made in different technologies.

Comment: The LS is lower power of course. The TTL Databook suggsts the only key difference is the voltage rating of the output transistors. 7446 : 30V, 7447 : 15V. Unless you're driving Nixie tubes this probably doesn't matter.